# Segmentation Fault in C program that is doing a binary search of an array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, binary, segmentation-fault

In this C program, I am doing a binary search of an array that I read in as data.txt

First I am trying to scan in the data.txt as an array
Second I am using an insertion sort algorithm to sort it
Third I am doing a binary search of the array. I am new to C and I have no idea where my code as gone wrong, thank you for any help in letting me know what I am doing incorrect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main ()
{
int v, t, low, high, mid, search;
int n = 20, array[20];
int p = 0;
FILE *infile;
infile = fopen(“data.txt”,”r”);

while(!feof(infile))
{
    fscanf(infile,”%d”, &array[p]);
    p++;
}


for (p = 0; p < n; p++) {
    scanf("%d", &array[p]);
}

for (p = 1 ; p <= n - 1; p++) {
    v = p;

    while ( v > 0 && array[v] < array[v-1]) {
    t          = array[v];
    array[v]   = array[v-1];
    array[v-1] = t;

    v--;
    }
  }
for (p = 0; p <= n - 1; p++) {
    printf("%d\n", array[p]);

printf("Please enter a value (-1 = done)>\n");
scanf("%d",&search);

low = 0;
high = n - 1;
mid = (low+high)/2;

while( low <= high )
{
    if ( array[mid] < search )
        low = mid + 1;    
    else if ( array[mid] == search ) 
    {
        printf("%d is located at %d in the array.\n", search, mid+1);
        break;
    }
    else
        high = mid - 1;

    mid = (low + high)/2;
}
if ( low > high )
  printf("-1\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n` is used in the first `for` loop without being initialized.

Comment: And that should be caught by the compiler if warnings are enabled. On Linux, compile with `gcc -Wall -g`, and learn to use the debugger `gdb`; you should enable warnings and use your debugger.

Comment: @Student... Initialize mean to assign/give some value to the variable. Currently the value of `n` is unknown when you are using it. In your current code you can do initialization as `int n = 20;`

Comment: alright, thanks for that knowledge

Comment: You are new to `C`. I recommend practicing some simple programs instead of jumping to complex algorithms and file handling.

Comment: I feel like I am really close, I just do not know what is tripping this program up so much

Comment: Possibly causing unexpected data or even writing past end of `array[]`: `while(!feof(infile))` is an antipattern for reading a file. See http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html and http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#4.2  This antipattern is likely responsible for your program looping more than you might expect when reading the file.

Comment: so the line instead should look like                             while(fgets(n, infile, p) != NULL)
    fputs(n, p);  ?

Answer (score 0):

1). initialize n with some value 
2). after the insertion sort (i guess) there is a printf to print the array. add another braces after the printf. if u dont this program keeps running(unless you enter a char which breaks the prog) but now it may work cause you are returning before it can loop but it is still a major problem..